# Replace ajax json for python json in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying change Ajax json url to python variable with a json in Django. As you can see the url in both cases are the same so I can't understand what is going on.
Thanks in advance.

What I'm looking for and does not work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#users').DataTable({
    "ajax": "{{ es_docs }}",
```

my view:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    context = {}
    context['segment'] = 'index'
    html_template = loader.get_template( 'index.html' )
    resp = requests.get("https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json").json()
    context['es_docs'] = resp
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

Template.html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#users').DataTable({
    "ajax": "https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json",
    'columnDefs': [
        {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
            }
        }
    ],
    'select': {
        'style': 'multi'
    },
    'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

`resp = requests.get(...)`

Returns a `response` object. To get the json data do this:

```py
response = requests.get(...)

if response.status_code != 200: 
    # handle errors:

else:
    json_data = response.json()

context['es_docs'] = json_data
```

Comment: Yes, I tryied but don't show me anything, only the table but without data